# Cannot disable Apache Spark writeAheadLogs

Tags: apache-spark

I set `spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable=false` and my history server confirms the property has been set.  Yet, I continue to see the error:

```
16/11/28 15:47:04 ERROR util.FileBasedWriteAheadLog_ReceivedBlockTracker: Failed to write to write ahead log after 3 failures
```

I surmised from the spark users thread [Spark Streaming Data loss on failure to write BlockAdditionEvent failure to WAL](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg58952.html) that HDFS append support must be enabled for WAL to work with HDFS.  My installation does not enable this HDFS feature, so I would like to disable WAL in Spark.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are checkpointinig on streamingContext something like this in your code:-

```
ssc.checkpoint(directory)
```

Spark does two type of checkpointing:-

1. Metadata checkpointing to recover from driver failures
2. Received data checkpointing

You are only disabling receiver checkpointing by using **spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable=false**

Metadata checkpointing is still on. And checkpointing needs the hdfs append feature.

You can enable hdfs append by setting the below given property in hdfs-site.xml :-

```
dfs.support.append=true
```